# React Native check if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am trying to check of a user is logged in using `SecureStore`.

Here is my logic:

`Login.js`

```
    const { token, setToken } = UseToken();
    const x = IsAuth(token);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (x) {
            navigate("/countries");
        }
    }, [navigate, x]);
```

`UseToken.js`

```
export default function UseToken() {
    const getToken = async () => {
        const tokenString = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("iScore")
        if (!tokenString) {
            return tokenString
        }
        return JSON.stringify(tokenString)
    };

    const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

    const saveToken = async userToken => {
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync("iScore", JSON.stringify(userToken))
        setToken(userToken);
    };

    return {
        setToken: saveToken,
        token
    }
}
```

`IsAuth.js`

```
export default async function IsAuth(token) {
    let exp
    try {
        exp = jwt(token)
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }

    if (Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) >= exp["exp"]) {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("iScore")
        return false
    }

    if (!token) {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("iScore")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

The issue is that `x` (which should either be a token or null depending if one is set in storage) is evaluating to `{"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}`.

I believe this is because x is being evaluated inside `useEffect` before it is being set by `IsAuth`, but I am not 100% sure. And because `x` is not null, the user is always being navigated away from the login page. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

in UseToken.js I think you call getToken in useEffect then setToken